# Perl HTTP::Request with File Upload ignores Headers

Tags: perl, http-headers, httprequest

I am trying to upload a file using Content-Type of 'form-data' in Perl with HTTP::Request.

The code looks like this:

```
$request = POST $URL,
                $headers,
                Content_Type => 'form-data',
                Content => [
                  'filename' => $args->{ formData }->{ filename },
                  'options'  => $args->{ formData }->{ options }
                ];
```

$headers is built using:

```
my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new();
while ( my ( $name, $value ) = each %{ $args->{ headers } } ) {
    $headers->header( $name, $value );
}
```

This is working PERFECTLY when calling other things that do not do file uploads with this call:

```
$request = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri, $headers );
```

When I look at the output from the file upload call, it does not have any header information other than:

```
Content-Length: 918
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY
```

However, there is another value set which should be in there.

If I remove "$headers" the output is identical.  I have also tried using

```
HEADERS => $headers,
```

but this just produces a header with the key of HEADERS, and a value of HASH(0x........)

I also tried adding

```
X-key-name => $value,
```

but that gives an error.  Surrounding the key with quotes doesn't add it to the headers.

I have looked for the past several hours in vain for even ONE example where a POST was done containing a file upload AND headers.

I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that

```
 HTTP::Request::Common::POST(...)
```

is not the same as

```
HTTP::Request->new(POST => ...)
```

but that the arguments differ.

According to the documentation in [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common)

```
   POST $url
   POST $url, Header => Value,...
   POST $url, $form_ref, Header => Value,...
   POST $url, Header => Value,..., Content => $form_ref
   POST $url, Header => Value,..., Content => $content
```

there is no documented way to use a HTTP::Headers object as the second argument.